# Angular 6 filter with breadcrumb shows error

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular6

I have done one application and I used breadcrumb in my application.

My code is like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';


import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { BreadCrumb } from './breadcrumb';

import { map, filter} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumb',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumb.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {


  breadcrumbs$ = this.router.events
  .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .map(event => this.buildBreadCrumb(this.activatedRoute.root));

    // Build your breadcrumb starting with the root route of your current activated route
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    buildBreadCrumb(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string = '',
                    breadcrumbs: Array<BreadCrumb> = []): Array<BreadCrumb> {
        // If no routeConfig is avalailable we are on the root path
        const label = route.routeConfig ? route.routeConfig.data[ 'breadcrumb' ] : 'Home';
        const path = route.routeConfig ? route.routeConfig.path : '';
        // In the routeConfig the complete path is not available,
        // so we rebuild it each time
        const nextUrl = `${url}${path}/`;
        const breadcrumb = {
            label: label,
            url: nextUrl
        };
        const newBreadcrumbs = [ ...breadcrumbs, breadcrumb ];
        if (route.firstChild) {
            // If we are not on our current path yet,
            // there will be more children to look after, to build our breadcumb
            return this.buildBreadCrumb(route.firstChild, nextUrl, newBreadcrumbs);
        }
        return newBreadcrumbs;
    }

}
```

BreadCrumbs HTML is this:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs$ | async"
        class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a [routerLink]="[breadcrumb.url, breadcrumb.params]">
        {{ breadcrumb.label }}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

If I compile this then it shows this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/share/components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.component.ts(20,4): error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'.
```

I have tried many times and searched Google but have not found the solution. Can anyone please help me and tell me where I’m wrong?

Comment: How can I use this in another component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the pipable operator

```
  breadcrumbs$ = this.router.events.pipe(
         filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
         distinctUntilChanged(),
         map(event => this.buildBreadCrumb(this.activatedRoute.root))
  );
```

[Doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Comment: How can I use this in another component?